# web scraping on Android app using Python

Tags: android, web, web-scraping

As a part of my final year project we are developing an android app.In here I'm going to do a web scraping part that allows user to take information through web.As i know most of the web scrapings are doing in Python.Is this possible to add this to an android app .

Comment: One popular library to use Android is Jsoup -- http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/

Comment: yes you can use jsoup or use XPath to web scraping in android